# How to print texts after some day(date) by awk

Tags: awk

Assuming that now is ( Tue Jul  7 23:33:33 2016 ), I want to process the past data within 2 weeks from now.
Meaning that I should just start printing data from (Tue Jul  3 12:24:52 2016) in the example below.

First, I think with below code I could show the date for 2 weeks ago with the related format like (Sat May 28 21:18:09 2016).

```
OS> date --date="14 days ago" | awk '{$5="";print $0;}' 
Thu Jun 23 22:49:47  2016
```

However, I am not sure how I can just print texts having a date late than the 2 weeks ago from now.

Do you have any idea?

## DATA

```
-- [1] Sat May 28 21:18:09 2016

blah

-- [2] Mon Jun 20 22:52:50 2016

blah

-- [1] Mon Jul 3 12:24:52 2016

blah
blah

-- [99] Mon Jul 3 09:24:52 2016

blah
blah

--
--
-- [33] Thu Jul 7 20:24:52 2016

blah
blah
```

## Desired output

```
-- [1] Mon Jul 3 12:24:52 2016

blah
blah

-- [99] Mon Jul 3 09:24:52 2016

blah
blah

--
--
-- [33] Thu Jul 7 20:24:52 2016

blah
blah
```

Comment: are the Day correct in your test data o/p file.. i can see it Tue for Jun 20. but it is mon.

Comment: I just put values in Data so it couldn't be correct. Modified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little different approach, if Data is in another file called Data, here is a shell script using awk.

```
#!/bin/sh

(date --date="14 days ago"; cat Data) | awk 'BEGIN \
    { table = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }

    { if (NR == 1) {
         x = index(table, $2)
         if (length(x) == 1) x = "0" x
         pt = $6 x $3 $4
#        print index(table, $2) " " $0 "    " pt 
         }
      if ($1 substr($2,1,1) == "--[") {
         x = index(table, $4)
         if (length(x) == 1) x = "0" x
         st = $7 x $5 $6
#        print index(table, $4) " " $0 "    " st
         prtsw = 0
         if (st >= pt) { prtsw = 1 }
         }
      if ( prtsw == 1 ) { print $0 }
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

run **awk -f script.awk file**

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN{
    FS="]";
    cmd="date -u +%s --date=\"14 days ago\""; #get Epoch time before 14 days
    cmd|getline start #set the time in start variable
}
/--[[:space:]]/{ #check for line starting -- 
    flag=0; # reset print flag
    cmd="date +%s -ud\""$2"\""; #get its epoch time
    cmd|getline check #set in variable check
} 
check>start {flag++;check=0} #set print flag
flag
```

---

**Output**

```
-- [1] Mon Jul 3 12:24:52 2016

blah
blah

-- [99] Mon Jul 3 09:24:52 2016

blah
blah

--
--
-- [33] Thu Jul 7 20:24:52 2016

blah
blah
```

Comment: It works but in case the file size is over 20MB, it shows an error. [cannot open pipe]. I guess it uses the pipe a lot. Thank you.